# Building a Go project with vendor dependencies across multiple projects

Tags: go

OK, so I have a few projects in Go that all share the same set of structs to represent my database schema. So to avoid code going out of sync, I moved all the structs into their own "models" project. My folder structure looks like this

```
GOPATH
  - src
    - project1
    - project2
    - models
  - pkg
  - bin
```

Models have some methods defined to fetch records from the database, but since each project needs to control its own database connection pool, I am passing the db connection to the model methods as an argument, so in models I have something like

```
import (
    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

type User struct {
    ...
}

type UserList []User

func (u *UserList) FetchAll(db *sqlx.DB) {
    ...
}
```

and in the project code, I have something like

```
import (
    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"

    . "models"
)

func UserListAPI(c *gin.Context) {
    var users UserList
    db := GetDBConnection()
    users.FetchAll(db)
    c.JSON(200, users)
}
```

But now, when I try to build, I get an error

`cannot use db (type *"project1/vendor/github.com/jmoiron/sqlx".DB) as type *"models/vendor/github.com/jmoiron/sqlx".DB in argument to users.FetchAll`

Is there any way to resolve this without drastically changing my project structure?

I am using `dep` to manage my dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution using a `src` directory:

1. Set your GOPATH to your project root.
2. Create a `src` directory in your project root. All your Go code should live in here.
3. Within the `src` directory, create a `vendor` directory. All your third party packages should live here. Dependency Management tools like GVT will install third party packages directly to this folder for you.

So your project should look like this:

```
- bin
- pkg
- src
    - project1
    - project2
    - models
    - vendor
        - github.com
            ...
```

To import third party packages within your code (for example from github.com), you would just use the github path directly, like `import "github.com/foo/bar"`. The Go compiler will use your GOPATH to determine that `github.com/foo/bar` actually lives at `$GOPATH/src/vendor/github.com/foo/bar`.

To import local packages, just use your local path directly, like `import "models"`. The Go compiler will use your GOPATH to determine that `models` actually lives at `$GOPATH/src/models`.

---

**Update**

Based on our conversation below, you have two options:

1. Consolidate the dependencies of all your projects into one vendor folder located at `$GOPATH/src/vendor`.
2. Use isolated projects and toggle your GOPATH to a new project root based on the project you're currently working on.

I would go with approach #2 to keep things clean and independent.

To achieve #2, you can create a structure like this:

```
- project1
    - bin
    - pkg
    - src
        - vendor
- project2
    - bin
    - pkg
    - src
        - vendor
```

To work on project1, set GOPATH to the root of project1. Same goes for project2 and any other projects you have.

Everything else I said above should still apply, because these projects still follow the same structure individually, but now we've also fulfilled the requirement of having a unique vendor directory for each project.

I know it's not "seamless" because you'll have to toggle your GOPATH, but I hardly think that is a big deal because you're only ever going to do that once in a blue moon, and it takes half a second. Plus, Golang was not made specifically to cater to such project structure requirements, though it is flexible enough to get it working without much hassle (all you have to do is toggle GOPATH).

You can even automate this further by writing aliases that change your GOPATH for you for certain projects. For instance, to switch to project1 really fast you can create an alias `project1` that runs the command `export GOPATH=/path/to/project1`.

---

**Update 2**

Here is how I structure a personal project of mine, which achieves everything you're trying to achieve:

```
- bin
- pkg
- src
    - vendor
    - core
    - apps
        - foo.com
        - api.foo.com
        - auth.foo.com
```

As you can see, in the `apps` folder I have multiple "projects" (though in reality these are just different binaries/HTTP servers).

You'll also see that I have a `core` directory. This is where all my shared logic lives. Each project in the `apps` folder can import from `core` with no problems since they're all within the same GOPATH namespace.

Comment: Sorry, but this is what I already have, I posted it wrong and I fixed the question

Comment: What do your imports look like? Are you sure your GOPATH is set to the project root in the terminal that your Go binary is running in? If you changed the GOPATH afterwards then you'll need a refresh of the terminal environment for it to pick up the new GOPATH.

Comment: It is not set at the project root, since I am working on multiple projects at once. All projects are under GOPATH/src. So the path to my vendor directory is something like GOPATH/src/project1/vendor

Comment: That is likely your problem. With the approach you are taking, it would work if you just use one vendor directory to manage dependencies for all projects, and it should be directly in the src folder. If you don't want to do that, then you should split up the projects. You can do something like `project1/src/vendor`, `project2/src/vendor`, and so on, and you would just toggle your GOPATH to be at the root of project1 or project2, respectively, depending on which project you're working on. That way each project will still have its own dependency management, and just toggle your GOPATH to switch.

Comment: If I do `project/src/` and set GOROOT for each project, I don't see how I will be able to import local packages. And making a shared vendor for all projects seems kinda ugly, how do I build individual projects? how do I use different versions of the same package for different projects? how do I make sure every binary doesn't get linked against every dependency ever?

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: So, if I go with path #2, how do I import things from one project in another project?

Comment: If you want to reuse code between projects, the clean way to do that would be through the vendor folder. Create a package and add it to the vendor directory of the project you want to share it with. This is a good approach because then you can version things properly..for instance one project uses v1.0.0 and can't upgrade for some requirements reason, yet another project can upgrade to the latest v2.0.0. If you use one shared piece of code - perhaps from a higher level package that both projects import (assuming that was even possible with your structure) - then you can't get this versioning.

Comment: To further elaborate, think of when you need a third party package from Github. What do you do? Something along the lines of `gvt fetch github.com/foo/bar` (which sends it to the vendor directory), and then `import "github.com/foo/bar"` within your code. This is the same approach, except it's with your own custom code and not third party code.

Comment: As I said in the question, I have multiple projects sharing code from a single custom library. The library changes a lot, since it is in active development. It is a proprietory codebase and it does not have its own repository as of now. And when it does, it will be inside another project written in a different language altogether. If I have to manually vendor this shared library into each project, I am losing all the safety of having common shared codebase.

Comment: I don't mean manually, I mean programatically. However you vendor your other third party packages, you should vendor this package the same way. But since you say it has no repository, that won't be possible. So my next idea would be to use a higher level package. But that requires all projects to be within one GOPATH namespace so they know where to import from, which brings us back to the original problem.

Comment: You can have multiple GOPATH's, however ["Go searches each directory listed in GOPATH to find source code and new packages are always downloaded into the first directory in the list"](https://dmitri.shuralyov.com/blog/18). This is why the approach #2 is necessary for your approach if you want individual vendor directories for each project. But that approach also makes it so that you can't use a "higher level package" to share code between multiple projects -- that would only be possible if all projects were within the same GOPATH namespace.

Comment: So, basically, what you are trying to do (as far as I am aware) is not possible. If you absolutely MUST have this "shared code", go back to your original approach using one GOPATH namespace for all projects, and share one vendor directory amongst them for the time being so that you can get going. Iterate on this later on when you have time and find a better approach; I don't think you'll run into those dependency problems anytime soon. Or if that isn't sufficient for you I would advise to keep looking. Let me know if you need additional help, I'd be happy to dig deeper when I get home.

Comment: Check my recent update to the answer. If you can tolerate one vendor directory, that is a solution that will achieve what you want.

Comment: So... basically you are telling me that there is no way to share code between Go projects without sharing every dependency as well?

Comment: You can do this. You just have to change your structure. The structure you're using has the limitations we've discussed above. You can set your GOPATH far up the directory tree, then have as many projects as you want and each of them can import code from one another. This doesn't follow the `src` pattern, though.

Comment: The way I understand, I can either have a common vendor directory, effectively sharing same set of dependencies between all projects or I can set GOPATH for every project which prevents me from importing local code.

Comment: Go will lookup your code like so: First `$GOPATH/vendor/package1`, second `$GOPATH/src/vendor/package1`, third `$GOROOT/src/vendor/package1`. So you can try adding packages to your GOROOT, and use approach #2 in the first update on my answer. That way, each project has it's own GOPATH tree (meaning they have their own vendor directory), and they can all still use globally shared code that you have somewhere in the GOROOT tree. Let me know if this works for you and I'll update my answer for the final solution. If not, let's keep iterating on ideas - we're almost there.

Comment: Sorry, I mean `$GOROOT/src/package1`, not `$GOROOT/src/vendor/package1`. The GOROOT path shouldn't have vendor; only the GOPATH should.

Comment: I am not sure. At this point I am confused. I have several projects. Code in one of them is shared by every other project. Each project (including shared one) has some vendored dependencies. I want to be able to import the shared project from other projects without 1. copying my code into every vendor directory 2. having a shared vendor directory across all projects and 3. still having all my code somewhere at the same level in the folder structure. That was my original question.

Comment: You can achieve all 3 of those points by going with #2 approach in my answer and also using the GOROOT as the location where your shared code lives. Try it and let me know what happens.

Comment: I am currently trying things with a shared vendor directory and also without any vendoring at all (setting GOPATH to the root of all projects and just using `go get` to install dependencies). The way you described in #2 doesn't work for me. It breaks my shared code imports, since shared code ends up outside of the GOPATH for the current project.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it seems that Go toolset was never designed for working on more than one project at a time and while it is making progress in that direction it is not quite there yet.